# SWIG python binding for c does not find _EXFUN for standard headers

Tags: python, c, arm, swig, msys

I am trying to use SWIG python binding for a c file. The c file compiles fine. The SWIG generated _wrap.c file does not compile because the compiler canot find the definitions for the _EXFUN coming from wchar.h getting included somehow.

```
int _EXFUN(wcsncmp, (const wchar_t *, const wchar_t *, size_t));
```

The environment is :
msys with arm-none-eabi.
Anaconda2-5.0.1-Windows-x86 32bit

I am in a deadend trying to find the cause. Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem occured while I tried to compile with gcc arm-none-eabi tool chain. And I could not solve the problem.

Then I changed the tool chain to TDM-GCC-32 and reorder the headers and the above issue disappeared. Still no idea why it is occuring with the arm-none-eabi option.